# Error message "The location of the document “Social Stats record Spreadsheet.numbers” cannot be determined"?

Tags: ios, mac, pdf, numbers, dropbox

I am trying to save my Numbers spreadsheet and this message (as stated in the question) is showing. I am also trying to export the file as a PDF and this message pops up -

The document “Social Stats record Spreadsheet.numbers” could not be autosaved. The file doesn’t exist.

I think this has something to do with me saving the file to dropbox as well as in my documents and the mac has got confused? I really don't want to lose my work as I've just updated it with a lot of info, how can I save the file and export it as a PDF without losing anything?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried saving it under a different name to a local directory - not dropbox?

Comment: @SolarMike I have and it still comes up with the same error message unfortunately

Comment: Ok, can you copy the cells then paste formulas into a new spreadsheet? That way you may be able to save what you have done...

Comment: I'm so glad for you - been there and had the panic!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of possibilities:

1) save to a different name in a local directory - not a network drive or dropbox,

2) open a new workbook and copy from the "old" workbook and paste-formulas into the new workbook

Either can save your work so it is not lost.